# how to have auto-completer in a QTableWidget cell that newly-created in pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to have auto-completer in my table cells and it is working but the problem comes when I add a new row to the table,
**1.** how can I add the same functionality to newly-created rows?
I use `_addRow` method to add a new row.
**2.** how can I add this functionality to the second or the third column of the table?
here I use `self.locs` for the first column and I need sth like `self.tech` to match the second column.
Here is the code:

```py
class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        completionlist = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        autoCompleter = QCompleter(completionlist,parent)
        autoCompleter.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        autoCompleter.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
        editor.setCompleter(autoCompleter)
        return editor
```

```py
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, df, action='Edit'):
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size:15px;')
        # Set table dimensions
        rows, cols = self.df.shape
        if action == 'Edit':
            pass
        elif action == 'Append':
            n = 4 # number of rows
            self.setRowCount(n)
            self.setColumnCount(cols)
            self.locs = self.df['LOCATION'].unique().tolist()
            #tech = self.df['TECHNOLOGY'].unique().tolist()

            self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list(self.df.columns))
            self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(50)
            self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
            self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, TableItemCompleter())
            #self.setItemDelegateForColumn(TableItemCompleter(), 2)# how can I have it for second col?
            for row in range(n-1):
                for col in range(self.columnCount()):
                    item = QTableWidgetItem('')#str(self.df.tail(n-1).iloc[row,col]))
                    item.setData(Qt.UserRole, self.locs)
                    self.setItem(row, col, item)
                    #self.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.df.tail(2).iloc[row,col])))
            self.cellChanged[int, int].connect(self.update_df)
            #self.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter())
        else: 
            pass
    
    def _addRow(self):
        rowCount = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(rowCount)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: So, in practice you want to be able to automatically set a different completer according to the column?

Comment: @musicamante that's right. and for new rows that the user creates.

Comment: `setItemDelegateForColumns()` already takes care of new rows. The problem is that you're setting the completer list on the index, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @musicamante thanks, what is the best way to set the completer list on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list of completer strings is the same for each column of the model, there's no use in setting that data on the index. A better solution is to initialize the delegate with a "matrix" of completions based on the columns.

```py
CompletionKeys = {
    0: 'LOCATION', 
    1: 'TECHNOLOGY', 
    2: ...
}

class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, completionMap, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.completers = {}
        for column, completionList in completionMap.items():
            completer = QCompleter(completionList, self)
            completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            completer.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
            self.completers[column] = completer


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        if index.column() in self.completers:
            editor.setCompleter(self.completers[index.column()])
        return editor


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, df, action='Edit'):
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size:15px;')
        # Set table dimensions
        rows, cols = self.df.shape
        if action == 'Edit':
            pass
        elif action == 'Append':
            n = 4 # number of rows
            self.setRowCount(n)
            self.setColumnCount(cols)

            self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list(self.df.columns))
            self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(50)
            self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
            for row in range(n-1):
                for col in range(cols):
                    item = QTableWidgetItem('')
                    self.setItem(row, col, item)

            completionMap = {}
            for col in range(cols):
                key = CompletionKeys.get(col)
                if key:
                    completionMap[col] = self.df[key].unique().tolist()
            self.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter(completionMap, self))

            self.cellChanged[int, int].connect(self.update_df)
```

Comment: `completer = QCompleter(completionList, self)
TypeError: index 0 has type 'int' but 'str' is expected` I get this error.

Comment: I don't know the contents of your data, if you're using integers obviously they cannot be directly used for completion. So, you either use `map(str, self.df[key].unique().tolist())`, or you check that the column does not contain any integer value. You have to find what's proper for the data you have, I cannot foresee any possible case for you.

Comment: you are right I should've built the dict like `{i:'{}'.format(val) for i, val in enumerate(df.columns[:2])}` as only first two columns are string. Thanks a lot. :)